# MySQL Group By slow even when indexed, and actual optimization makes no sense

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Uses: MySQL 5.7, entire dataset is known to be cached in OS memcache on Linux.
Engine is InnoDB

```
SELECT colA, colB, count(*)
FROM someTable use index (idx_someTable_Date_colA_colB)
WHERE Date >= ? and Date < ?
GROUP BY colA, colB;
```

Performance of the above is non-linear and quickly degrades to 10x slower than the next query construction:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMPT;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMPT (
  colA bigint(20),
  colB varchar(50)
) 
AS (
  SELECT colA, colB
  FROM someTable use index (idx_someTable_Date_colA_colB)
  WHERE Date >= ? and Date < ?
);
SELECT colA, colB, count(*)
FROM TEMPT
GROUP BY colA, colB;
```

I cannot find any reasonable explanation as to why, for large data sets, the second query style should be 10x faster than the first.  First, the original data has a multi column index that covers the exact columns of interest.  Second, the faster version requires creating a separate table that copied all of the data at least once, and then does a table scan of the unindexed temporary.

Why is the first construct very slow, while the second construct achieves performance equivalent to Postgresql??

---

Profile for top query:

```
# Status, Duration
'starting', '0.000046'
'Waiting for query cache lock', '0.000012'
'starting', '0.000013'
'checking query cache for query', '0.000164'
'checking permissions', '0.000022'
'Opening tables', '0.000054'
'init', '0.000077'
'System lock', '0.000025'
'optimizing', '0.000048'
'statistics', '0.000206'
'preparing', '0.000068'
'Creating tmp table', '0.000172'
'Sorting result', '0.000032'
'executing', '0.000030'
'Sending data', '48.525629'
'Creating sort index', '0.016266'
'end', '0.000042'
'query end', '0.000030'
'removing tmp table', '0.001459'
'query end', '0.000024'
'closing tables', '0.000020'
'freeing items', '0.000052'
'cleaning up', '0.000049'
```

---

Profile for bottom query (create temporary/insert):

```
# Status, Duration
'starting', '0.000310'
'checking permissions', '0.000034'
'checking permissions', '0.000019'
'Opening tables', '0.000098'
'init', '0.000256'
'creating table', '0.023076'
'After create', '0.000056'
'System lock', '0.000038'
'optimizing', '0.000037'
'statistics', '0.000274'
'preparing', '0.000058'
'executing', '0.000017'
'System lock', '0.000040'
'Sending data', '3.877377'
'Waiting for query cache lock', '0.000047'
'Sending data', '0.000017'
'end', '0.000012'
'query end', '0.000705'
'closing tables', '0.000031'
'freeing items', '0.000070'
'cleaning up', '0.000038'
```

---

Profile for bottom query (select from temporary):

```
# Status, Duration
'starting', '0.000069'
'Waiting for query cache lock', '0.000018'
'starting', '0.000009'
'checking query cache for query', '0.000102'
'checking permissions', '0.000025'
'Opening tables', '0.000016'
'init', '0.000111'
'System lock', '0.000036'
'optimizing', '0.000020'
'statistics', '0.000051'
'preparing', '0.000049'
'Creating tmp table', '0.000090'
'Sorting result', '0.000045'
'executing', '0.000016'
'Sending data', '0.273446'
'Creating sort index', '0.002288'
'end', '0.000052'
'query end', '0.000027'
'removing tmp table', '0.000022'
'query end', '0.000017'
'closing tables', '0.000018'
'freeing items', '0.000064'
'cleaning up', '0.000057'
```

Comment: Are you comparing only the `group by` or creating the temporary table and doing the `group by`?  Also, why do you have `date` in the `select` for the first query?

Comment: You didn't use `EXPLAIN`. You didn't use `profiling`. So, naturally, it's not clear what MySQL is doing. Had you used the two I mentioned, you'd definitely have a clearer picture of what the optimizer does and what the OS/MySQL are doing to find and send your data. So, give it a try and then come back with updates?

Comment: remove the "use index" and use explain as already suggested. also consider changing "Date >= ? and Date < ?"  to between

Comment: The inclusion of the "Date" in the first select is a typo.  I retyped the query to mask the column names and such.  I am comparing the total time to execute the entirety of each code block.  Ie, the time it gets me to compute an answer from scratch.  The explain shows that it uses the index, "using index condition, using temporary, using filesort" while the latter query obviously doesn't use the index condition on table TEMPT.

Comment: I can confirm that Date >= ? and Date < ? yields the same efficiency as BETWEEN, or using "IN" with an enumerated list of dates.  Please trust me that the problem is *not* trivial.  The "insert into temporary table" statement should take at least as long as just grouping directly to begin with, but it does not.  The number of records from the group by yields several thousand records, but overall this should be as difficult in either case.

Comment: I've added profile information, but unfortunately, it just says it spent 48 seconds "sending data", which I'm pretty sure MySQL does not do client side, so I don't know what that even means. (In another stackoverflow message, someone points out that there is a bug that buckets execution time into the sending data bucket, so that's what it is doing.)

Comment: As always, Profiling is useless.  Most of the time is spent in the un-informative "Sending data" phase.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (There may be some surprises in the datatypes and/or indexes.)

Comment: Did you try `INDEX(colA, colB, Date)`?  A relatively new optimization may kick in for that ordering.

Comment: Is it InnoDB?  What is the size of the table and values of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `tmp_table_size`?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the detailed EXPLAIN output (preferrably in JSON format since it have more details) in order understand what is going on.  One cause for the different performance may be that different grouping/aggregation algorithms are used in the two cases.  One may sort before grouping, or one may incrementally increase the counts in a temporary table as the rows are read.  The two approaches may give different performance.

Note that you do not need to create an explicit temporary table.  You can put the first query in a subquery in the FROM-clause (called a derived tabled):

```
SELECT colA, colB, count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT colA, colB
  FROM someTable use index (idx_someTable_Date_colA_colB)
  WHERE Date >= ? and Date < ?
  LIMIT 100000000
) dt
GROUP BY colA, colB;
```

Note the LIMIT with a large number.  I use that prevent the optimizer from merging the subquery into the outer query.